# Which ruby version is installed?

Tags: ruby, version, rvm, upgrade

Sounds strange but I cannot tell which ruby version is installed. If I do

```
rvm rubies
```

I get

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 [ i686 ]
```

but with

```
ruby -v
```

I get

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-linux]
```

When trying to

```
rvm upgrade 1.8.7-p302 1.9.2-p180
```

I get an error

```
ERROR: Ruby 'ruby-1.8.7-p302' is not installed - please install it first.
ERROR: Error migrating gems.
```

So, which one is it? 1.8.7-p302 or 1.9.2-p180 ???

Please help me out here! Thanks

Comment: What is the output of rvm list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get `1.8.7` from the installed version of your system. Use `rvm use --default 1.9.2` in order to set the Ruby installed via `rvm` as default.

RVM basically changes your `$PATH` variable to point to a different Ruby version than the one installed on your system.

Please also make sure that you have done steps 2 and 3 of the [installation guide](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) and confirmed that RVM is correctly set up.

Answer (score 0):

You might have 1.8.7 because you did `sudo apt-get install ruby` or something like that, and then later ran `rvm install 1.9.2`. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is both as mentioned by other posters. As a recommendation you should uninstall the ruby packages that come with the system if you choose to manage ruby version using rvm.